# jquery click event run one time only

Tags: click, jquery

im having a problem with the click event. It run one 1 time. Example:

I have 3 pages(1 2 3). when i click in the 2 it work. then in the 3 page and it work again. But i click in the 2 agains doesnt work. The event is not triggered.

```
$("div .top.pagination a").click(function(){  

 PagNrClick = $(this).text();
            PagNrOld = $(".top.pagination .current").text();    
            RegMin = (NrReg-1)*(PagNrClick-1);


            //altera a pagina activa para por selecionar
            $(".top.pagination .current").replaceWith('<a title="'+PagNrOld+'" href="#'+PagNrOld+'" rel="history">'+PagNrOld+'</a>');
            //altera a pagina que clicou para activa
            $(this).replaceWith('<span class="current">'+PagNrClick+'</span>');             

            if(RegMin%2 || RegMin%0){
                RegMinValue = RegMin;
            }else{
                RegMinValue = RegMin+1;
            }
            //:gt(0) - greater then 0 não mostra a 1º posição(BUG DO JQUERY??????)
            if(PagNrClick==1){
                $("#thumbs li:eq(0)").show();
            }
            //esconde todos os registos e mostra os 12 proximos registos
            $(".thumbs li:visible").hide();
            $(".thumbs li:gt("+RegMinValue+"):lt("+NrReg+")").show();
});
```

i have insert the code into jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/B2Usk/1/

Comment: Don't you think `.top.pagination` is wrong?

Comment: no its correct. its 2 classes in on div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div .top.pagination").on('click', 'a', function(){
    /* ... Youre event code ... */
});
```

You can also use .live() in previous versions.But it is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to the `replaceWith` call which replaces the Html in the DOM and effectively unbinds the event. If you use jQuery `prop`, `attr`, and `text` functions to update the link properties this should resolve the issue.

Alternatively storing the event handler in a variable and rebinding in the handler would also resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

replace `click` with `on`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/B2Usk/2/)**

```
$("div .top.pagination").on('click', 'a',function(){
            PagNrClick = $(this).text();
            PagNrOld = $(".top.pagination .current").text();    
            RegMin = (NrReg-1)*(PagNrClick-1);


            //altera a pagina activa para por selecionar
            $(".top.pagination .current").replaceWith('<a title="'+PagNrOld+'" href="#'+PagNrOld+'" rel="history">'+PagNrOld+'</a>');
            //altera a pagina que clicou para activa
            $(this).replaceWith('<span class="current">'+PagNrClick+'</span>');             

            if(RegMin%2 || RegMin%0){
                RegMinValue = RegMin;
            }else{
                RegMinValue = RegMin+1;
            }
            //:gt(0) - greater then 0 não mostra a 1º posição(BUG DO JQUERY??????)
            if(PagNrClick==1){
                $("#thumbs li:eq(0)").show();
            }
            //esconde todos os registos e mostra os 12 proximos registos
            $(".thumbs li:visible").hide();
            $(".thumbs li:gt("+RegMinValue+"):lt("+NrReg+")").show();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are deleting the `<a>`-Tag, so the click handler detaches.

Consider using `.on()` instead of click. It's behaviour and syntax is descibed here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Basically instead of `$("div .top.pagination  a").click(function(){ /* ... */ });`

you call the following:

```
$("div .top.pagination").on('click', 'a', function(){
    /* ... Youre event code ... */
});
```

Comment: The same page also mentions **version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9**

Comment: use on(), live is deprecated.